# Yii criteria brings order alias of table

Tags: yii

I have a method to get fields from related tables in my Table1 model:

```
public function getFields()
{

    $sort = new CSort();
    $sort->attributes = array('field1','field2');

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select = "t3.xxx as field1, count(t1.id) as field2";
    $criteria->alias = "t1";
    $criteria->join = "inner join Table2 t2 ON t1.id_table2=t2.id";
    $criteria->join .= " inner join Table3 t3 ON t2.id_table3=t3.id";
    $criteria->group = "field1";
    $criteria->order = "field2 desc";

    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>50,),
            'sort'=>$sort,

    ));
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

In the controller:

```
public function actionListfields()
{
    $dataProvider=Table1::model()->getFields();

    $this->render('index_listfields',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

In the index_listfields:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
            'field1',
            'field2',   
        ),
    ));
```

I am getting the Grid with the right headers and 28 lines, that is the right size of my query. But I am getting no results in the colmuns. If I try to click in the headers to "suposely" order a column, I get an error saying an strange thing: it says my sql is trying to use an alias at the order command inside the sql, like this:

```
SELECT t3.field as field1, count(t1.id) as field2 FROM "Table1" "t1" inner join Table2 t2 ON t1.id_table2=t2.id inner join Table3 t3 ON t2.id_table3=t3.id GROUP BY field1 ORDER BY "t1"."field2" DESC LIMIT 50
```

I don know why the order clause is getting the t1 prefix, but the app is complaining about it.

I also don't know if I am doing the right way what I want. I first tryed to accomplish this by using plain SQL. I could bring the values of the fields, but I could not order them in the gridview.

I would like some advice, please!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try by adding a property in the `Table1` class file as `public $field2`. This way the table will actually have such a field.

Comment: Thanks Kunal!! I am almost there. Including the fields in the class worked to bring the values. But the order still doesn't work! :(

Comment: Please try my new answer. It should work all fine now.

Comment: Kunal, I figure it out! I solve the problem by removing the order clause from the criteria: $criteria->order = "field2 desc";
I don't know why, but it worked!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change -

`$sort->attributes = array('field1', 'field2');`

with

```
$sort->attributes = array(
    'field1' => array(
        'asc'=>'field1 ASC',
        'desc'=>'field1 DESC',
    ),
    'field2' => array(
        'asc'=>'field2 ASC',
        'desc'=>'field2 DESC',
    )
);
```

It works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didn't work. I had to delete the order criteria: $criteria->order = "field2 desc".

Answer (score 0):

> I also don't know if I am doing the right way what I want. I first
>   tryed to accomplish this by using plain SQL. I could bring the values
>   of the fields, but I could not order them in the gridview.

This is probably because the SQLDataProvider returns an Array instead of an object.